# Is there a way to check if any raycast hits the collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I have a `GameObject` with a box collider and a `Player` script attached to it.

I want a Function Like This (`CheckAnyRaycastIntersection()`):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] BoxCollider bxCollider;

    void Update()
    {
        bool i = bxCollider.CheckAnyRaycastIntersection();

        print(i); //Prints TRUE if any Raycast intersects with bxCollider
                  //Otherwise prints FALSE
    }
}
```

This is useful for me when I'm trying to find out if any gun is targeting the `Player`. So I want the 'Player' script to calculate this.
[Check the GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2gT1.gif)
I know there are many ways to do it, but can I do it this way?

Comment: well ... no, there is an infinite amount of potential raycasts .. could you add some more details about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to do this,

If you want to see gameObject colliding with something else, use the spherecast or boxcast.

In this scenario you should explain who is throwing raycast and who should or should not intersect with the ray.

If you can explain more, i can help.